# How to capture ExtJS Graph line name click event

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a graph as shown below, currently if I click "Name1" ExtJS hides that line from the graph. But I want to make a call to server and refresh graph after this click event. How do I capture this click event on "Name1"?

[image]

Comment: LegendItem has mousedown and click events for your purpose.